# Combining numbers and units with a multiplication sign to show dimensions

Tags: siunitx

Using the [`siunitx`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx) (or any other) package, is there a way of combining numbers and units with a multiplication sign? For example, I'd like to give a sheep pen size of 1.5 m × 2.5 m. I can do it with numbers only (e.g., `\num{1.5 x 2.5}`), but can't find a way to do it with units.

Comment: `$\SI{1.5}{\meter}\times\SI{2.5}{\meter}$`?

Comment: You're right @egreg, not sure why I was trying to complicate it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it also with units:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\SI[product-units=repeat]{2x3}{m}

\end{document}
```

You can set the `product-units=repeat` option globally with `\sisetup` (but it's the default, so it's not even needed).

[image]

Comment: Now that's the sort of neat solution I like!  Many thanks @egreg.

Comment: With version 3 of `siunitx`, the `\qtyrange` command is offered: `\qtyrange{2x3}{\meter}`