# Notation and output in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}

\newcommand*\something[3]{
  \SIlist[
    list-separator = #1,
    list-final-separator = #1,
    list-units = brackets
  ]{#2}{#3}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  l
  &= \SI{38.0}{\cm} + 2 \cdot \SI{26.2}{\cm} + \SI{32.6}{\cm}\\
  &= \something{+}{38; 52.4; 32.6}{\cm}\\
  &= \SI{123.0}{\cm}.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The `\something` command works just fine when there is only either `+` or `-` but can I create a similar command when both plus and minus are used?

Comment: Can you add an example of what you mean by "when both plus and minus are used".  If you are thinking of `\something{+}{38; -52.4; 32.6}{\cm}` for example,  and you don't want a `+ -52.4` in the output, then this can be done with other list processing methods, but don't know about `siunitx`.

Comment: @PeterGrill I'm trying to create a macro where the output is the same as the output from, say, `\SI[parse-numbers = false]{(38{,}0 - 52{,}4 + 32{,}6)}{\cm}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\SIexpr{ m m }
 {
  \svend_siexpr:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \svend_siexpr:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_svend_siexpr_input_seq { ; } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_svend_siexpr_input_seq \l_svend_siexpr_first_tl
  \seq_clear:N \l_svend_siexpr_output_seq
  \seq_put_right:Nx \l_svend_siexpr_output_seq
   {
    \fp_compare:nTF { \l_svend_siexpr_first_tl > 0 }
      { \num { \l_svend_siexpr_first_tl } }
      { - \num { \tl_tail:V \l_svend_siexpr_first_tl } }
   }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_svend_siexpr_input_seq
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l_svend_siexpr_output_seq
     {
      \fp_compare:nTF { ##1 > 0 }
        { + \num { ##1 } }
        { - \num { \tl_tail:n { ##1 } } }
     }
   }

  \SI[parse-numbers=false]
   {
    \sisetup{parse-numbers}
    ( \seq_use:Nn \l_svend_siexpr_output_seq { } )
   }
   { #2 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  l
  &= \SI{38.0}{\cm} + 2 \cdot \SI{26.2}{\cm} + \SI{32.6}{\cm}\\
  &= \SIexpr{38.0; 52.4; 32.6}{\cm}\\
  &= \SI{123.0}{\cm}.\\
  l
  &= \SI{38.0}{\cm} - 2 \cdot \SI{26.2}{\cm} + \SI{32.6}{\cm}\\
  &= \SIexpr{38.0; -52.4; 32.6}{\cm}\\
  &= \SI{18.2}{\cm}.\\
  l
  &= \SI{-38.0}{\cm} + 2 \cdot \SI{26.2}{\cm} + \SI{32.6}{\cm}\\
  &= \SIexpr{-38.0; 52.4; 32.6}{\cm}\\
  &= \SI{47.0}{\cm}.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The argument to `\SIexpr` is split into components.

- The first component is detached to be treated separately.
- Each component is examined for seeing if it is positive or negative: if negative we add `-\num{<absolute value>}` else `+\num{<absolute value>}`.
- However, a leading `+` is not added by doing a special examination to the first component.

To have the separator in the first mandatory argument to `\SIexpr` selectable with an optional argument, change the main code into

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\SIexpr{ O{;} m m }
 {
  \svend_siexpr:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \svend_siexpr:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_svend_siexpr_input_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_svend_siexpr_input_seq \l_svend_siexpr_first_tl
  \seq_clear:N \l_svend_siexpr_output_seq
  \seq_put_right:Nx \l_svend_siexpr_output_seq
   {
    \fp_compare:nTF { \l_svend_siexpr_first_tl > 0 }
      { \num { \l_svend_siexpr_first_tl } }
      { - \num { \tl_tail:V \l_svend_siexpr_first_tl } }
   }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_svend_siexpr_input_seq
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l_svend_siexpr_output_seq
     {
      \fp_compare:nTF { ##1 > 0 }
        { + \num { ##1 } }
        { - \num { \tl_tail:n { ##1 } } }
     }
   }

  \SI[parse-numbers=false]
   {
    \sisetup{parse-numbers}
    ( \seq_use:Nn \l_svend_siexpr_output_seq { } )
   }
   { #3 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Now you can do

```
\SIexpr{38.0; 52.4; 32.6}{\cm}
```

or

```
\SIexpr[,]{38.0, 52.4, 32.6}{\cm}
```

or even

```
\SIexpr[?]{38.0 ? 52.4 ? 32.6}{\cm}
```

If you prefer a comma by default, instead of a semicolon, you should have

```
\NewDocumentCommand\SIexpr{ O{,} m m }
```

The default separator can't be a colon, but you can select a colon with the optional argument.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Sorry, I thought to a simplification while writing the answer and forgot to add `\num`. Fixed.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Yes, of course; only a semicolon appears in the code, change it to `,`. One could make it selectable as an optional argument.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Yes, they are because of usage of `\fp_abs:n`; a slower routine would be necessary to keep it.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Done, it turned out not to be so difficult as I thought initially.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I don't think that ⅜m makes any sense.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I fully disagree. This isn't a correct usage of numbers. The sooner students are taught what they are doing, the fewer mistakes they'll make. The difference between abstract measure and real world measure should be underlined as soon as possible.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg No, I won't indulge in what I consider wrong. Sorry.

Comment: Hi once again, egreg. I actually have another (trivial?) problem: How do I multiply two numbers inside `\SIexpr`? Using either `*` or `\cdot` gives an error.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg This code only accepts addition (and subtraction). Do you need a full fledged parser for math expression? Sorry, my opinion is that ***even*** additions shouldn't be treated this way, but as “remember the unit, do the computation on numbers and reinsert the unit”.  If you need multiplication of two factors, it's already available, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204373/combining-numbers-and-units-with-a-multiplication-sign-to-show-dimensions