# Notation and output in siunitx, II

Tags: siunitx

This is a follow-up question to "[Notation and output in siunitx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207161/notation-and-output-in-siunitx)".

Consider the following code ([courtesy of egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207185/15874)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\SIexpr{ O{,} m m }
 {
  \SIextension_siexpr:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \SIextension_siexpr:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_SIextension_siexpr_input_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_SIextension_siexpr_input_seq \l_SIextension_siexpr_first_tl
  \seq_clear:N \l_SIextension_siexpr_output_seq
  \seq_put_right:Nx \l_SIextension_siexpr_output_seq
   {
    \fp_compare:nTF { \l_SIextension_siexpr_first_tl > 0 }
      { \num { \l_SIextension_siexpr_first_tl } }
      { - \num { \tl_tail:V \l_SIextension_siexpr_first_tl } }
   }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_SIextension_siexpr_input_seq
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l_SIextension_siexpr_output_seq
     {
      \fp_compare:nTF { ##1 > 0 }
        { + \num { ##1 } }
        { - \num { \tl_tail:n { ##1 } } }
     }
   }

  \SI[parse-numbers=false]
   {
    \sisetup{parse-numbers}
    ( \seq_use:Nn \l_SIextension_siexpr_output_seq { } )
   }
   { #3 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  l
  &= \SI{-38.0}{\cm} + 2 \cdot \SI{26.2}{\cm} + \SI{32.6}{\cm}\\
  &= \SIexpr{-38.0, 52.4, 32.6}{\cm}\\
%  &= \SIexpr{-\frac{38.0}{1}, 52.4, 32.6}{\cm}\\
  &= \SI{47.0}{\cm}.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The code compiles just fine but assume I want a fraction as in the out-commented expression with automatic scaling of the parentheses.

How do I achieve that?

**Update**

I tried to change a single code line from

```
( \seq_use:Nn \l_SIextension_siexpr_output_seq { } )
```

to

```
\left( \seq_use:Nn \l_SIextension_siexpr_output_seq { } \right)
```

in order to get scaling parentheses but without luck; with or without the code change I get the following error when trying to use a fraction inside `\SIexpr`:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                           Erroneous variable \protect used!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools,mleftright}
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\SIexpr{ O{,} m m }
 {
  \SIextension_siexpr:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \SIextension_siexpr:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_SIextension_siexpr_input_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_SIextension_siexpr_input_seq \l_SIextension_siexpr_first_tl
  \seq_clear:N \l_SIextension_siexpr_output_seq
  \seq_put_right:Nx \l_SIextension_siexpr_output_seq
   {
    \fp_compare:nTF { \l_SIextension_siexpr_first_tl > 0 }
      { \num { \l_SIextension_siexpr_first_tl } }
      { - \num { \tl_tail:V \l_SIextension_siexpr_first_tl } }
   }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_SIextension_siexpr_input_seq
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l_SIextension_siexpr_output_seq
     {
      \fp_compare:nTF { ##1 > 0 }
        { + \num { ##1 } }
        { - \num { \tl_tail:n { ##1 } } }
     }
   }

  \SI[parse-numbers=false,quotient-mode=fraction]
   {
    \sisetup{parse-numbers}
    \mleft( \seq_use:Nn \l_SIextension_siexpr_output_seq { } \mright)
   }
   { #3 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  l &= \SI{-38.0}{\cm} + 2 \cdot \SI{26.2}{\cm} + \SI{32.6}{\cm} \\
    &= \SIexpr{-38.0, 52.4/12, 32.6}{\cm} \\
    &= \SI{47.0}{\cm}.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Gives no errors to me.

What did I do? I added the option `quotient-mode=fraction` to `\SI[…]` so you can use `/` to obtain a fraction.

By the way, I would load `\usepackage{mleftright}` and use `\mleft( … \mright)` rather than `\left( … \right)`.

[image]

Comment: Not ``\`` but `/`.

Comment: Sorry. Of course! I actually did use `/` but simply forgot the option. Embarrassing that I missed that, since I use [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) quite often.

Comment: May be it's “more correct” if you pass `quotient-mode=fraction` to `\sisetup` rather than `\SI[…]`. But I leave that to you.

Comment: Btw. if you can make `\frac{}{}` work, that would be really cool, but I can do fine with the other solution!

Comment: I actually have another (trivial?) problem: How do I multiply two numbers? Using either `*` or `\cdot` gives me an error.

Comment: Just searching `*` in the siunitx.pdf documentation: `input-product=*` and `output-product=\cdot` options should give you what you want. Put those options in the same place you put `quotient-mode=fraction`.

Comment: Damn! I have to remember to emvoke both of them at the _same_ time; I tried both but not at the same time. Thank you, Manuel.