# Command not 'legale' in .sty file

Tags: package-writing

Consider the following style file `goat.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2014/05/01]
\ProvidesPackage{goat}[2014/10/16 goat]

\DeclareOption{mammalbirdfish}{
\makeatletter
 \begingroup
  \catcode`\_=\active
  \protected\gdef_{\@ifnextchar|\subtextup\sb}
 \endgroup
\def\subtextup|#1|{\sb{\textup{#1}}}
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\_=12 \mathcode`\_=32768}
\makeatother}

\ExecuteOptions{mammalbirdfish}
\ProcessOptions
```

When I try to load the package in my LaTeX document be executing `\usepackage{goat}`, I get the following error:

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.13 \ExecuteOptions{mammalbirdfish}
```

How do I get the above chunk of code into my style file?

P.S. I've never written a style file before so please forgive me if my question has a trivial answer.

**Update**

I also can't put

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

into my style file

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2014/05/01]
\ProvidesPackage{goat}[2014/10/16 goat]

\RequirePackage{expl3}

\DeclareOption{macros}{
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
}

\ExecuteOptions{macros}
\ProcessOptions
```

When I compile the doucment

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{goat}

\begin{document}

test

\end{document}
```

it gives the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\ds@makroer ...scriptfalse \par \ExplSyntaxOn \cs 
                                                  _new_eq:NN \calc \fp _eval...
```

How do I fix this?

(Let my know if I should ask the update question as a new one; it was put here because I *think* it might be a similar problem.)

Comment: I don't know if this has a trivial answer, but in my (yet small) experience, the trick for run a local `*.sty` file is storing it in the same directory where is the `*.tex`file where you load that file. I know there is a way to store it in a local directory and there invokes it whenever you need but I don't do it yet.

Comment: @Aradnix I don't see how that has got anything to do with my question. I know where to put the file but not how to execute the code mentioned.

Comment: Don't use `\makeatletter... \makeatother` in `.sty`, `.cls` etc. files. `@` is already a letter in this context. You only need these in documents (preferably in the preamble). [I don't suppose this is the problem. Just 'by the way...'.]

Comment: @cfr Thanks for the pointer! (No, that's not the problem.)

Comment: If you create a new `\if` and use the option to toggle the `\if`, then you can execute the code after `\ProcessOptions` conditionally. E.g. `\newif\ifmammalbirdfish
  \mammalbirdfishfalse` and then put `\mammalbirdfishtrue` in the option declaration and the code which is currently there in an `\ifmammalbirdfish ... \fi` after `\ProcessOptions`.

Comment: I don't get an error if I just add that code to the package file. Can you post an MWE? EDIT: Obviously, you need `\RequirePackage{expl3}` first...

Comment: Oh. Yes. That doesn't surprise me. Don't put it into the `\DeclareOption`. Use the Option to toggle a switch and put the code after `\ProcessOptions`. You might want to look at one of the packages for handling keys if you are doing a lot of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see what happens with

```
\DeclareOption{mammalbirdfish}{
\makeatletter
 \begingroup
  \catcode`\_=\active
  \protected\gdef_{\@ifnextchar|\subtextup\sb}
 \endgroup
\def\subtextup|#1|{\sb{\textup{#1}}}
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\_=12 \mathcode`\_=32768}
\makeatother}

\ExecuteOptions{mammalbirdfish}
\ProcessOptions
```

The code from `\makeatletter` to `\makeatother` is given as argument to `\DeclareOption`, so it has already been tokenized and, in particular, the `_` after `\gdef` has category code 8, so it's illegal after `\gdef` when the code is *executed* (storing it is not a problem, as TeX doesn't interpret commands at that moment).

It's (almost) never needed to issue `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in a class or package file, because they are read with implicit `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` at the end. To be more precise, these commands in a class or package file usually are wrong, unless they appear as part of a macro definition. In this case they are *wrong*, because when `\ProcessOptions` expands the code for the `mammalbirdfish` option, `\makeatother` will ruin all subsequent reading of the code in the class or package.

Note that setting that code as an option which is executed no matter what is nonsense: such an option should never be passed to `\ExecuteOptions`.

However, the most important problem is the category code of `_`. I'll show a different strategy than setting a conditional and doing the code after `\ProcessOptions` if the conditional is true.

```
\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\_
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \DeclareOption{mammalbirdfish}{%
    \protected\gdef~{\@ifnextchar|\subtextup\sb}%
    \def\subtextup|#1|{\sb{\textup{#1}}}%
    \AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\_=12 \mathcode`\_=\string"8000 }%
  }%
}
```

which works because there's no uppercase character token in the code and so only `~` (which is already active) will be converted to (active) `_`.

Similar problems are with

```
\DeclareOption{macros}{
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
}
```

which should be

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareOption{macros}{
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

otherwise the characters `:` and `_` would have be tokenized as “other characters”.

Comment: Can you tell me where to put `\DeclareOption` if I want to put your code from [Notation and output in siunitx](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207185/15874) in a `.sty` file?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Why would you add an option for that? It's a command, just define it.

Comment: I just made the assumption that I had to define an option for it. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure my comment isn't less clear than mud, but this is too much code for a comment - sorry. Happy to delete it later if best.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2014/05/01]
\ProvidesPackage{goat}[2014/10/16 goat]

\newif\ifmammalbirdfish
\mammalbirdfishfalse
\DeclareOption{mammalbirdfish}{%
  \mammalbirdfishtrue}

\ExecuteOptions{mammalbirdfish}
\ProcessOptions
\ifmammalbirdfish
  \begingroup
    \catcode`\_=\active
    \protected\gdef_{\@ifnextchar|\subtextup\sb}%
  \endgroup
  \def\subtextup|#1|{\sb{\textup{#1}}}%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \catcode`\_=12 \mathcode`\_=32768}%
\fi
```

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Well, I don't know why. I just know things are different when you are declaring options than later.

Comment: Sorry for 'un-accepting' your answer; I really like egreg's explanations and what I believe to be improvements to the answer.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg His answer is much better than mine although I don't completely understand it. You should ***definitely*** accept that answer!