# Loading order in .sty file

Tags: packages, best-practices

With [help from egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208097/15874), I have the following collection of packages and macros in the file `standardopsaetning.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2014/05/01]
\ProvidesPackage{standardopsaetning}[2015/01/04 Standardopsætning]


\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{lmodern}
\RequirePackage{babel}
\RequirePackage[
  hmargin = 2.4cm,
  vmargin = 3cm
]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{mathtools}
\RequirePackage[
  bottom,
  hang,
  stable
]{footmisc}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{caption}
\RequirePackage{siunitx}
\RequirePackage{pstricks-add}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\RequirePackage{upgreek}
\RequirePackage[
  lastpage
]{zref}
\RequirePackage{microtype}


\mathtoolsset{
  showonlyrefs
}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{tilpasning}{:\quad}
\captionsetup{
  labelsep = tilpasning,
  figureposition = bottom,
  tableposition = top,
  font = small,
  labelfont = sc
}
\sisetup{
  locale = DE,
  per-mode = symbol-or-fraction,
  range-phrase = --
}
\psset{
  dimen = m
}

\newif\ifprint
\newif\ifsubscript

\addto\extrasdanish{
  \renewcommand*\pageautorefname{side}
  \renewcommand*\figureautorefname{\textsc{Figur}}
  \renewcommand*\tableautorefname{\textsc{Tabel}}
}

\providecommand*\setfloatlocations[2]{\@namedef{fps@#1}{#2}}
\setfloatlocations{figure}{htbp}
\setfloatlocations{table}{htbp}

\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = T1}

\setlength\footnotemargin{6pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{14.5pt}
\zref@newprop*{numpage}{\the\value{page}}
\zref@addprop{main}{numpage}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{%
  \ifnum \zref@extractdefault{LastPage}{numpage}{0} > 1
    \thepage
  \fi
}

\begingroup\lccode`\~=`\_
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \protected\def~{\@ifnextchar|\subtextup\sb}%
}
\def\subtextup|#1|{\sb{\textup{#1}}}%
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\_=12 \mathcode`\_=\string"8000 }

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n

\NewDocumentCommand\SIexpr{ O{,} m m }
 {
  \SIextension_siexpr:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \SIextension_siexpr:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_SIextension_siexpr_input_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_SIextension_siexpr_input_seq \l_SIextension_siexpr_first_tl
  \seq_clear:N \l_SIextension_siexpr_output_seq
  \seq_put_right:Nx \l_SIextension_siexpr_output_seq
   {
    \fp_compare:nTF { \l_SIextension_siexpr_first_tl > 0 }
      { \num { \l_SIextension_siexpr_first_tl } }
      { - \num { \tl_tail:V \l_SIextension_siexpr_first_tl } }
   }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_SIextension_siexpr_input_seq
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l_SIextension_siexpr_output_seq
     {
      \fp_compare:nTF { ##1 > 0 }
        { + \num { ##1 } }
        { - \num { \tl_tail:n { ##1 } } }
     }
   }

  \SI[
    parse-numbers = false,
    quotient-mode = fraction,
    input-product = *,
    output-product = \cdot
  ]
   {
    \sisetup{parse-numbers}
    \left( \seq_use:Nn \l_SIextension_siexpr_output_seq { } \right)
   }
   { #3 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\endinput
```

I then start a `.tex` file with the following:

```
\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}

\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt,
  danish
]{article}

\usepackage{standardopsaetning}

...
```

**Question:** Is this 'correct' or is there a better loading order or should I change something else? (As an example, I'm not sure if `lmodern` is loaded in the best place.)

Comment: To answer some of your questions, it would be helpful to know what kinds of documents you intend write with this package. Separately, rather than ask if `lmodern` is loaded at some optimal stage, I'd be tempted to ask if `lmodern` is the most suitable font family and if `12pt` is the optimal font size for your typesetting needs. Finally, I strongly recommend inserting loads more comments into the file. You may know right now why certain packages are being loaded and why others are not, but I can guarantee you that in six months you'll be much less sure about these things.

Comment: @Mico Latin Modern and a font size of 12pt is what I use for the documents I'm loading `standardopsaetning.sty` in. I have _a lot_ of notes/comments in the 'real' style file but they are in Danish so I removed them here.

Comment: One practical suggestion about the package: I think it's good practice to keep together instructions that load various packages and macros that make use of the packages to achieve certain things. For instance, I'd place the instruction `\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = T1}` immediately after `\RequirePackage{microtype}`. Similarly, it might make sense to place the instruction `\setlength\footnotemargin{6pt}` immediately after the loading of the `footmisc` package.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that you do have lots of comments. (It hadn't occurred to me that they might be in Danish, but that of course makes perfect sense!)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, Mico! Others are more than welcome to give their inputs, too. `:)`

Comment: It is, of course, a mistake to load `lmodern` rather than the alternative at all... ;). But if you insist, I would also load `textcomp`.

Comment: @cfr What is the alternative? `:)`

Comment: `cfr-lm`. [I'm joking about loading `lmodern` being a mistake. `cfr-lm` is an alternative, though.] I think there's another one, but `cfr-lm` is better or I wouldn't have bothered to write it.

Comment: `\RequirePackage{pkgloader}` :-)

Comment: I suspect this should be closed as "too broad" (or "unclear") there is no general right answer for package loading, however the order does not matter unless two packages (re) define the same command. This is rather unlikely for the packages that you list, you are not loading multiple font commands or multiple table packages or multipe cross-ref packages even hyperref (which has to redefine more or less everything so interacts with many packages)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I decided to not load [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) in this `.sty` file because I sometimes have packages which should be loaded _after_ hyperref. Sometimes I have a few more table packages in my documents (together with [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) but I've never experienced any problems in this regard).

Comment: @SvendTveskæg yes but that doesn't leave anything that anyone can really comment on, I voted to close, sorry:-)

Comment: To all who voted for closing the question because it is unclear what I'm asking: How and why is it unclear? I think it's perfectly clear. `:(`