# Problem with siunitx code after package update

Tags: siunitx

Consider the following MWE where the code comes from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207161/notation-and-output-in-siunitx/207185#207185) and is then modified a bit:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\SIexpr{O{,}mm}{
  \SIext:nnn{#1}{#2}{#3}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \SIext:nnn#1#2#3{
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_SIext_input_seq{#1}{#2}
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_SIext_input_seq \l_SIext_first_tl
  \seq_clear:N \l_SIext_output_seq
  \seq_put_right:Nx \l_SIext_output_seq{
    \fp_compare:nTF{\l_SIext_first_tl > 0}
      {\num{\l_SIext_first_tl}}
      {-\num{\tl_tail:V \l_SIext_first_tl}}
  }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_SIext_input_seq{
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l_SIext_output_seq{
      \fp_compare:nTF{##1 > 0}
        {+\num{##1}}
        {-\num{\tl_tail:n{##1}}}
    }
  }

  \SI[
    parse-numbers = false,
    quotient-mode = fraction,
    input-product = *,
    output-product = \cdot
  ]{
    \sisetup{parse-numbers}
    \left(\seq_use:Nn \l_SIext_output_seq{}\right)
  }{#3}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\SIexpr{5, -2*1}{\s}

\end{document}
```

Whan I compile via `pdflatex` using my up-to-date TeX Live 2021 distribuion, I get the following warning and error:

```
Package siunitx Warning: Option "quotient-mode" has been removed in this
(siunitx)                release.


! LaTeX3 Error: The key 'siunitx/input-product' is unknown and is being
(LaTeX3)        ignored.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.41 \SIexpr{5, -2*1}{\s}
```

How do I fix the code in order for it to compile properly once again?

Comment: Have you looked at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598236/siunitx-3-quotient-mode-has-been-removed-in-this-release :

Comment: the answer you linked too didn't use `input-product` and in combination with `parse-numbers = false` it looks a bit odd there. In any case if you want products, you will have to check the documentation for `\numproduct` and `\qtyproduct`. Also I don't think that you can use *, you will have to use x for the product.

Comment: The code in my answer works with the new release of `siunitx`.

Comment: @egreg Thank you, Enrico! Assume that I have defined, say, `\def\horse{45}`. Then I cannot use `\SIexpr{200, -2*\horse}`, but I have to put `2*\horse` inside an `\fpeval{}`. Can this be changed so that I don't have to use `\fpeval{}`?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the expected output.

Comment: @egreg It should be `110` (= 200 - 2*45) in this case. I have this issue in quite a few documents so it would help me alot if this can be "fixed". (I think the problem is that `input-product` isn't suppoered anymore but I'm not sure.)